# WireShark beginner, capturing the ethernet driver

Tags: networking, network-programming, wireshark

I'm new to WireShark, I'm trying to test it, I was walking through this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHLTa29iovU&feature=related
He was capturing his ethernet driver and once he opened his browser, he saw the packets transaction in WireShark. I don't know how I am able to capture my ethernet driver also, BTW I'm using WiFi, if it matters, here are my interfaces:
http://img862.imageshack.us/img862/6154/wirep.png

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and install the vendor driver instead of the Windows default one, but this is not assured to help. On my PC it is working fine.

With WiFi interfaces/drivers, [PCAP](http://www.winpcap.org/) (the capture engine) is not behaving well as with wired ones. Usually it is the driver blame by not implementing the API.

You can also try to capture on the WiFI interface (the one you see the IP on) by checking off the promiscuous mode on the interface (press "options" instead of "start" and do the change).

Good luck.

Comment: you accepted this answer. did you install a vendor driver or did you just capture the wifi interface?